# Props Shortening in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I have started a Udemy tutorial for JS and I am a bit confused in which cases we can use this kind of shortening, changing

```
onTermChange = { newTerm => setTerm(newTerm)}
onTermSubmit={() => searchApi()}
```

to

```
onTermChange = {setTerm}
onTermSubmit = {searchApi}
```

and I wonder when we can use this kind of shortening in our props in JavaScript.

Comment: Are these React props that you're referring to?

Comment: For the general purpose question, you should go read about "Javascript destructuring assignment".  Here's [one reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). That's the general topic and there are many, many ways to use it.  It would be inappropriate to try to create a whole tutorial here on all the ways it can be used.  It would make more sense for you to read about all the ways it can be used and then ask a specific question about one particular use.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think this is destructuring in this case, I think OP is referring to [JSX props](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx) from React :)

Comment: @NickParsons - Maybe that's what they mean, but the question does not state that at all.  In fact, the question says: ***Udemy tutorial for the JS***. So, your guess is as good as mine until the question gets clarified.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, fair enough. "Props" is usually a term used within react so that's why I'm guessing it's React, but it could very well be a question about destructuring/short-hand property names as well. I guess OP needs to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function into `onTermChange` and `onTermSubmit`. In your first examples you are creating new functions, and then passing those in. In the second examples, you're not creating any functions, you're just passing in ones that already exist.

So if you have functions that already do what you want, you can go with option two. If you don't have the functions you need yet, then go with option 1. For example, maybe your current functions are expecting parameters that don't match what the event callback does. In that case, you'll need to create a new function which does that for you:

```
onTermChange={newTerm => setTerm(newTerm, index)} // where index is some other variable defined above this
```